# Flow doesn't recognize implementing class inside a callback parameter that takes a callback

Tags: flowtype

I have the following setup:

```js
/* @flow */
interface ISelectable {
onSelectUntil(callback: (data : ISelectable) => void, until : (callToRemoveCallback : Function, callback: (data : ISelectable) => void) => void): void;
}

class BaseFileTile implements ISelectable {
  onSelectUntil(callback: (data : BaseFileTile) => void, until : (callToRemoveCallback : Function, callback: (data : BaseFileTile) => void) => void) : void {}
}
```

The problem is that this throws:

```
7:   onSelectUntil(callback: (data : BaseFileTile) => void, until : (callToRemoveCallback : Function, callback: (data : BaseFileTile) => void) => void) : void {}
                                                                                                                        ^ Cannot implement `ISelectable` [1] with `BaseFileTile` because `BaseFileTile` [2] is incompatible with `ISelectable` [3] in the first argument of the second argument of the second argument of property `onSelectUntil`.
References:
6: class BaseFileTile implements ISelectable {
                                 ^ [1]
7:   onSelectUntil(callback: (data : BaseFileTile) => void, until : (callToRemoveCallback : Function, callback: (data : BaseFileTile) => void) => void) : void {}
                                                                                                                        ^ [2]
3: onSelectUntil(callback: (data : ISelectable) => void, until : (callToRemoveCallback : Function, callback: (data : ISelectable) => void) => void): void;
```

[try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgOwC4FMBOUAhgMa5gCSAyrjLidkQEZ1gDeqcmNdDAqjnQwAFCSIwYTUgGsAXGGEATIozDzqteoxa4AlGAC8APjAA3OOkUAaMAFdBMNQrESAKnABKuALZxTuAGFxSRknADF7BnQuGxcQkjkFZVV1Hi1mOn1jMwtFLJNzS115QsUAblQAX1RUEhgiAGcGsAAhRtwwoVxXLrB0bwAHOm9cHGaNXm1WDjAwLjT+B1FgqQT5JRUiJzaGjq6ezMMC3Jt7bCEnZbdPHz9AldD5CMwomLA41cSNlNb2zroDnojjkisDSvoSrl2NVqkA)

While in the first callback Flow correctly recognizes that `BaseFileTile` is of type `ISelectable` but in the other callback an error is thrown. Is this behavior wanted or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. This has to do the possibility that the `callback` function modifies its `data` argument. Specifically, if the callback function accepts an `ISelectable` it can interact with `data` in any way that preserves its `ISelectable` type. Thus, `callback` could potentially modify a `BaseFileTile`, breaking its type as a `BaseFileTile` but maintaining its type as an `ISelectable`.

To make this work, you will want to mark the `data` argument as "read only" by using the [`$ReadOnly` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUIBsILHAIx2QG8AoAexExzwFVxgsAKBOLLAxAawC5lmAEzj5k-DNlz4iEAJTIAvAD5kANwrBBAGmQBXRljEC2HACoUAShAC2FVRADC7TjyMAxfXmBUdJlwj4BYVF+ABIrOEEAeRAsAE8AHglaaRwleWU1DUEMlXVNWX58wQBuMgBfMjIELDgAZzrkACF6iDcmCFMO5GBrAAccawhwRuSpQmJyZGQqGikGMCZWZy4A-iEROCMWuraOrpxcrM0dfUXDdb9zK1t7Jw5V7ndPRZ9kP0f14K2wiOjYxI7PY4A4QdKKPLZI7FeRFbKkSrlIA)). This tells Flow that the `data` argument will not be modified and so a `BaseFileTile` will remain as a `BaseFileTile`.

Comment: But why does the first callback parameter pass type checking while the second nested callback doesn't? [try it](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUIBsILHAIx2QG8AoZZAexExzwFVxgsAKBOLLAxAawC5krACZx8yQRmy58RCAEpkAXgB8yAG5VgwgDTIArsywShHLgBUqAJQgBbKuogBhTtz4mAYobzAaes24IAkKi4pJ0MoQ4iqoaWsIxapra8oLJwgDcZAC+ZGQIWHAAzkXIAELFEB4sEOY1yMC2AA44thDgpVL0ssTklDQRjEbsrjxBgiJicCYVRVU1ddHKSfF6hmAsJiMW1nYOzqPugl4gPn7IAWPBk2Fogz0Ky3EpT+mKafGkudlAA) Could you give an example showing the difference?

Comment: [Found an example where it errors](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAkgygYQIYBsUCMkGMDWUC8scEKEWwS6pBAfFAG4D2AlgCYDcAUKJEQKoA7YMxQEoACgBiAVwHlmjAQBoiyNJlwBKWgxYdO3cNABCkgCpqM2PIWNIAzhEkiIZlzqZsuPE+cHDRQilZeUUVUwtUKy0PPS5OZiEIACcAM2xoeBIyCipoAG9OKCgAehKoLCiNHAAuVSrrLmKyqEViUnJ-ETrxeEtqlXgulG18Ok99ZvLZALqhoREuAF8DLBQHeyg7R2dSN2pmAFswUkOIIU2sjtzqQqmoAFFk5MZkqHQyJGlHVtSoVOYyXswCgSGSAHNpGchEVSuVKuprHUIv1GrDYS0ni83h9Kt9oIw-gCgSCwZDoSDCRUGrgMeU2tlOgsUD0UTScOE-MzRuM4lB0fcsa93p98b8oI4sIpWKCIVDzpS-jMRHTWgJ2jlhj0+uzOWZhjzdF4BXDHs9hbivj8qcTgbLyQrxQjojhVQzrlqJGzEbhBnADbFjcVVUKcaLrX9JdL7fKYfdlSytlyAstOEA)

Comment: I'm not sure why yet, but I've been looking into how to reproduce the error. Maybe you can see any differences/mistakes I've made in the example. I'll comment with any more updates I have. I think both the arguments should be erroring because of the issue I mentioned and because of the example I found, but you're totally right that it doesn't error in the example you posted. Very strange behavior (unless I'm totally overlooking something in my example).

Comment: Posted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909106/flow-function-variance-producing-different-errors) that will help answer your question here. I wasn't able to figure out what was causing the difference. Hopefully someone more familiar with Flow can help us both out.

Comment: Seems like it got accepted as a bug for now: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7678 Could be some kind of inconsistency. We'll see as the future unfolds...